# What should be the 5th dimension for the input to 3D-CNN while working with hyper-spectral images?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a hyperspectral image having dimension `S * S * L` where `S*S` is the spatial size and `L` denotes the number of spectral bands.

Now the shape of my X (image array) is: `(1, 145, 145, 200)` where 1 is the number of examples, 145 is the length and width of the image and 200 is no. of channels of the image.

I want to input this small windows of this image (having dimension like `W * W * L`; W < S) into a 3D CNN, but for that, I need to have 5 dimensions in the following format: `(batch, length, width, depth, channels)`.

It seems to me I am missing one of the spatial dimensions, how do I convert my image array into a 5-dimensional array without losing any information?

I am using python and Keras for the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convolve along the dimension of your channels, you should add a singleton dimension in the position of channel.  If you don't want to convolve along the dimension of your channels, you should use a 2D CNN.

Comment: By adding a singleton dimension do you mean reshaping it to `(1, 145, 145, 200,1)`.

Comment: Yep, or you can use `tf.expand_dims(X, axis=4)`.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a 2D CNN, not a 3D one. A 2D CNN already supports multiple channels, so you should have no problem using it with a hyperspectral image.

Comment: No, actually I am trying to implement a research paper, so I specifically want this done using a 3D CNN as it has some advantages according to the paper. Hence, I want to implement the proposed method and see how that works! I've already done this once using 2D CNN as you suggest.

Comment: @gopalkrizna What paper exactly? It could be that this paper mentions 3D convolution but it is actually the same as Keras' 2D convolution.